# Format text to left

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, trim, nl2br

I am creating a format tool that strips content from articles for print. The demo can be seen [here](http://tools.knowconceptdesign.com/stripr/). The full source is avaliable [here](http://code.google.com/p/stripr/).

Right now the tool strips formating and can also keep paragraphs by using `nl2br` What I would like to do is to be able to shift the content to the left and only have a paragraph if there is a break between the content.

for example:

> This
>   is
>   the
>   first
>    paragraph
>
> Second Paragraph

Becomes:

> this is the first paragraph
>
> Second Paragraph

I tried this by using regex to check if there were two spaces at the end but that didn't work. Here is some sample code:
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea cols="68" rows="21" name="textinput"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="keep_paragraphs" value="true" checked /> Keep Paragraphs<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="shift_left" value="true" /> Remove whitespace after line unless it ends in two spaces<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
$text= $_POST['textinput'];
        $p= $_POST['keep_paragraphs'];
        $lb= $_POST['shift_left'];
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $text = stripslashes($text);
        // strip off the slashes if they are magically added.
        }
        $text = htmlentities($text);
        //if we should keep formatting
        if($p=="true"){
            $text =nl2br($text);
        }
        if($lb=="true"){
            $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($text));
        }
echo $text;
```

Any help on this would be great

**EDIT:** include example

> POST textbox =  "Hi Jane
>
> How are You doing today
>
> I hope all is well";

Most text will be coming from e-mails and other sources,basicly it needs to be super genderic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is,

`/(?<!\r\n)\r\n(?=\w)/`

replace it with a space.

**Update**

A small correction,

```
$text ="This
is
a
paragraph  

Second Paragraph";

$lb = "true";
if($lb=="true"){
            $text2 = preg_replace('/(?<!\r\n)\r\n(?=\w)/', ' ', trim($text));

        }

echo $text2;
```

Comment: It seems to work on codepad but not on my actual software is `htmlentities`, `stripslashes` or `nl2br` going to do something to the formatting and break the preg_replace?

Comment: try `/(?<!\r*\n)\r*\n(?=\S)/` - made it more generic, also if you can paste real inputs after `htmlentities` and `nl2br` I can fine tune the regex.

Comment: That produces a php error: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 9` http://codepad.org/yVC1rJkf P.S. Thanks!

Comment: please give a sample of real data you are dealing with.

Comment: The text is coming from a text box. More or less people will be copying from e-mails and such. I added an example above. It also may be a php problem with my host not seeing `/r/n`

Answer (score 1):

Your can write this

```
$text = preg_replace('@\n([a-z])@Us', ' \1', trim($text));
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaking that is adding 2 spaces before the text http://codepad.org/htGXDmuC

Comment: Use this `$text = preg_replace('@\s*?\n*\s*([a-z])@Us', ' \1', trim($text));`

Comment: Thanks @azat, that is super close, it's just adding a space between each letter. http://codepad.org/ylikDz0e If i remove the space in `'\1'` the second paragraph works but the first has no spaces. Thanks for your help.